# More useful placeholder for hidden spoilers in question summary

Tags: feature-request, question-lists, spoilers, question-summary

I just noticed that [spoilers are now hidden from the questions page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89552/can-we-please-remove-spoilered-text-from-the-summary). Well, it's been a while, but at the same time I noticed something bad about this reading [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9017/how-is-jackie-still-alive-after-another-intimate-encounter) in the overview (using IE9):

For example, the question

```
How did they know that
>! John Doe
was the murderer?
```

If I'm right, this should result in the following teaser text (e.g. shown in a tooltip when hovering the question on the list):

```
How did they know that was the murderer?
```

What I don't like here is the fact that the spoiler is hidden (nice), but you don't immediately notice there's something hidden (bad).

So what I'd like to ask is, skipped spoiler text to be shown similar to this:

```
How did they know that [...] was the murderer?
```

That way it's immediately clear that there's something missing, and given the context it's also quite clear that it's obviously some spoiler text.

Comment: I'd take it half a step further: `How did they know that [spoiler] was the murderer?`  Really spell it out that here there be spoilers.