# Spoilers are not hidden in inbox notifications

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox, spoilers

Text inside spoiler blocks is not properly hidden in Inbox notifications.

1. User A posts a question.
2. User B posts an answer with a spoiler near the beginning of the post.
3. User A opens their inbox notifications and sees the spoiler.

Screenshot of the problem below (contains minor spoilers for Xenoblade Chronicles 3)

> [image: Answer with spoiler displaying unblocked in notification]

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this issue was addressed for several areas previously, not including this one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89552/can-we-please-remove-spoilered-text-from-the-summary/113889#113889 sounds like they never actually completed implementing that fix

Comment: @KevinB but this never mentioned notifications, it didn't ask to remove the spoilers from all the places.