# Hide code in question summary

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not include code blocks in abbreviated question summaries on the question listing pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24123/do-not-include-code-blocks-in-abbreviated-question-summaries-on-the-question-lis)

While searching through questions I have frequently noticed that the summary is taken up almost entirely by the code snippet or ASCII art that is part of the question. Here is an example:

[image]

I would argue that seeing the unformatted code is not very useful to you as you are browsing questions cursorily. It also prevents you from reading more of the actual prose, which helps you decide whether you can be of assistance to the asker.

Would you agree that replacing code snippets in the summary with a delimited ellipsis is a good idea?

Comment: I would have to do extra clicks in _every_ question I chose to read.

Comment: I suppose you mean to censure only blocks of code, not code inlined in sentences. Right ?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I don't see how that would be the case. Just to clarify, I am requesting this for question *summaries*, not the actual questions.

Comment: @dystroy Correct. Martin, yes that question is quite similar, it didn't show up in the suggestions though. Is it going to be implemented?

Comment: @Asad: I have no idea if that suggestion is going to be implemented; there is no status flag on that suggestion.

Comment: @Asad, sorry, I have misunderstood you =(

Answer (score 0):

Very often, as you saw, the code in the summary doesn't really make sense.

But most often, even without being clear, it gives a hint about the topic.

Look at this :

[image]

In the first and third question, I got information from the included code snippet and it was useful to me. In both cases, the code we see in the summary is taken in separate code paragraphs, not from code inlined in sentences.

So, even if it's very far from perfect, I'd prefer to have this code kept in the summary rather than removed.